# Outer merge two dataframe in python where the left dataframe is larger than the first

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series, outer-join

I am trying to perform an outer join (union) of two time series in python.
The left time series is larger than the first.

An example:

Right time series - *df_1*

| Time | Series 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

Left time series - *df_2*

| Time | Series 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 13 |
| 4 | 14 |
| 5 | 15 |
| 6 | 16 |

I simply tried:

`pd.merge([df_1, df_2], how = "outer", on = "Time")`

I expected to get something like this:

| Time | Series 1 | Series 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nan | 10 |
| 1 | nan | 11 |
| 2 | nan | 12 |
| 3 | 1 | 13 |
| 4 | 2 | 14 |
| 5 | 3 | 15 |
| 6 | nan | 16 |

Instead I got this:

| Time | Series 1 | Series 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 13 |
| 4 | 2 | 14 |
| 5 | 3 | 15 |
| 6 | nan | 16 |

It is crucial for the exercise to keep the time series in the correct sequence, I do not want to switch the order of the merge.

Comment: I think I have solved it using the `pd.reindex()` function I was not aware of. basically you can provide a list like mapping and the dataframe columns are rearranged automatically! I simply have to understand how to structure the merging procedure but I believe it would only take few conditional statements and the game should be done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using 'outer' in how argument you can use 'right'.
Below is the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['time 3', 'time 4', 'time 5'],
     'Series 1': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['time 0', 'time 1', 'time 2', 'time 3', 'time 4', 'time 5', 'time 6'],'Series 2': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]})

merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Time', how='right')
merged_df = merged_df.sort_values('Time')
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index(drop=True)
merged_df['Series 1'] = merged_df['Series 1'].fillna(np.nan)
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I ended up using `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Time', how='outer')` using conditional statements and `pd.reindex()` to get the columns in the correct order I wanted. The problem was a bit more complicated then the one I have presented. Anyway your answer is super useful and correct indeed.